# Laravel 5 route get parameters SQLinjection

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a route like this

```
Route::get('/car-{travelType}/{cityFrom}-{cityTo}-{id}.html','ArticleController@getDetail')->name('articles_detail');
```

And in my controller, I catch parameters like this

```
public function getDetail($cityFrom, $cityTo, $id, Request $request)
{
    $article_detail = DB::select("CALL article_detail(?,?,?)", [$cityFrom,$cityTo,$id]);
    return $article_detail;
}
```

This will working fine but there have a problem that this query getting sqlinjection because route sent raw parameter.

In post request I can catch request like `$request->input('some_fields')` and laravel protect me behind the screen, but not in get request.

How can I resolved that issue?

Comment: You're already protected against SQL injection when you use `DB::select` as long as you're passing in user supplied data as the second parameter and using `?` in your sql.

Comment: @LoganBailey Oh well, it's true. Thanks so much, sorry for my bad, I have not tested the code before ask :(

Comment: those aren't query string variables they are route parameters

Answer (score 0):

you can use $request->get('somefield') also on Get request using

```
www.site.com/page?somefield=value
```

in this case when you take $request->get('somefield') it should give you "value"

so in your case :

```
www.site.com/page?travel-type=foo&city-from=berlin&city-to=munich&id=1

$request->get('travel-type'); // foo
$request->get('city-from');   // berlin
$request->get('city-to');     // munich
$request->get('id');          // 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my url it's not perfomance param like yours, it's like `site.com/some-thing/some-thing-1352.html` and `$request->get('id')` is not working